Python 3.12: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools' Ubuntu 24.04
i try to use a tool names awsume which i installer per pipx.
unfortunately, i cant use the configure mode (awsume-configure).
I get the following Error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.local/bin/awsume-configure", line 5, in <module>
    from awsume.configure.main import main
  File "/home/username/.local/share/pipx/venvs/awsume/lib/python3.12/site-packages/awsume/configure/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from awsume.configure import post_install
  File "/home/username/.local/share/pipx/venvs/awsume/lib/python3.12/site-packages/awsume/configure/post_install.py", line 1, in <module>
    from setuptools.command.install import install
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'

I use the Python version:
Python 3.12.3
python3-setuptools   68.1.2-2ubuntu1


Try installing setuptool using pipx

You can install setuptools with
sudo apt install python3-setuptools


Like i said, i already use python3-setuptools   68.1.2-2ubuntu1
